# Does dark matter get drawn into black holes?

Tags: gravity, black-holes, dark-matter

Would dark matter get drawn into a black hole?

Also, could enough dark matter be concentrated to create a "dark black hole"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Could Dark Matter form black hole?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/90908/)

Comment: "could enough dark matter be concentrated to create a "dark black hole"?" I don't know if blackholes made of dark matter exists but in wikipedia there is image where is concentrated dark matter which curves space around it: [Image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Gravitationell-lins-4.jpg) or more info at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_matter#Galaxy_clusters_and_gravitational_lensing)